# How can I convert number of days to month or a year

Tags: sql, sql-server

| col1 | convert |
| --- | --- |
| 30 days | 1 month |
| 45 days | 1 month 15 days |
| 365 days | 1 year |

Comment: What's 31 days? 364 days? 366 days in a leap year?

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: What about the months that have 28 days? 29 days? 31 days?

Comment: Note that 364 days gives you 12 months, 4 days.

Comment: There may be an assumption of standard amount of days, which is 365 for the year and 30 for the month: it may not be linked to specific months/years.

Comment: It may be an invalid assumption. For a non-leap year with 365 days your 12 months would have 30.4166' days. It's like assuming days always have 86400 seconds, which doesn't account for leap seconds or daylight savings time changes.

Comment: It depends. If you're doing an approximation and you don't need that kind of accuracy, leap years are irrelevant in the count of days for any year on average. Only the OP can tell more about this. @AlwaysLearning

Comment: There is no magic here nor any standard function / formula. This is just standard units conversion - just like converting ounces to quarts and to gallons. Your ouput suggests you want a string and your sample data is rather convenient since there is no "left over" amount that cannot be converted. Define what your actual goal is, use realistic sample data, and define what results you want from that sample data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Would be nice to see what you have done and make it right for you.

But do you have a way to do it:

```
    [YEARS] = @days / 365,
[MONTHS] = (@days % 365) / 30,
[DAYS] = (@days % 365) % 30.
```

here you have 3 formulas for and convert from days to moon, year and days